# Permissioning the registry via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, permissions, registry, acl

I'm trying to remove user permissions from a registry key using PowerShell, but having difficulty. The currently logged on user (User.Test) has full control of the key `Internet Settings`, but when running the script below as a scheduled task it fails to successfully remove the user. Can someone help?

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted
$acl = Get-Acl -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
$acl | Format-List
$user = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Domain\User.Test")
$permission = [System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights]"FullControl"
$inherit = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None
$propagation = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None
$type = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule($user, $permission, $inherit, $propagation, $type)
$acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($rule)
$acl | Set-Acl
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)` instead of `$acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($rule)`.